# Error installing a python module

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, setuptools

I am trying to install a python module with the standard `python setup.py install` but I get the following error. I am fairly new to python but I have been able to install other modules in this way in the past. I am under the impression this module `setuptools` is not something I am supposed to have gotten separate from my python installation. Do I need to be in a specific directory or something?

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3 in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Comment: I am on a Win 7 system using python 2.6

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apparently, that package requires you to have setuptools to install it. Setuptools is a module that provides easy installation of Python packages. You can get it on pypi, [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Comment: Thanks interjay and Pakars. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, setuptools does NOT come pre-packaged with Python, despite how often and casually everyone refers to it. I also had this problem when learning Python.

Setuptools is available on the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11).