# Couldn't install pip and selenium in windows7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am using python 2.7. I have downloaded the files `selenium-2.28.0` and unzipped to the `C:\Python27` . Then running the command `python setup.py install` but getting an error. I am using 32 bit windows 7 pc

```
C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0

C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0>python setup.py install
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0>setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools

C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0>
```

What could be the reason? the same for unzipped file `pip-1.2.1` to the same folder as `selenium` is happening.

Can you guide me here?

**EDIT**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Arup Rakshit>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\>C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0
'C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0' is not recognized as an internal or external comma
nd,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>cd C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0

C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0>c:\python27\python.exe setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools

C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0>
```

Comment: please help me to install it.

Comment: @Ross Patterson can you help me?

Comment: try C:\Python27\selenium-2.28.0>c:\python27\python.exe setup.py install

Comment: you need python in your "PATH", so when you type python on the command line it just runs. That's a start. See here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7

Comment: @PaulC see my **EDIT** not working! please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641131/error-installing-a-python-module

Comment: @PaulC no improvement,I really stuck here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I have solved my issue by easy_installer. I have installed all the needed packages with python2.7.

here is the Youtube link [easy_installer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssQAFIQ4oBU)

Hope this would help other too!