# install Pybrain in Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: python, installation, windows-7-x64, pybrain

Hi everyone i was new for python, i have a problem for install pybrain in windows 7(64 bit)

it show an error while using command mode (run as administrator) 
Traceback:
  File "C:\Pybrain-0.2.1\setup.py",line 11 in 
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools

please help thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@interjay have answered in this question: [Error installing a python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641131/error-installing-a-python-module)

> Apprarently, that package requires you to have setuptools to install it. Setuptools is a module that provides easy installation of Python packages. You can get it [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).